# Open Browser Window with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, browser

How do I open a browser window (Safari) with Ruby on a Mac and pass it a url?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
`open #{url}`
```

Comment: i mean so it actually opens the browser window visibly, not just so I can read the response data.

Comment: Did you try it? With the ``backticks``? It does exactly what you're after :)

Comment: @viatropos, I tested this and it works. Make sure you incude include the `\`` characters.

Answer (score 5):

Basically the same as Peter's answer, just more explicit.

```
system("open -a Safari #{url}")
```